# When are conics geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesics

Does there exists a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or an open subset of it) such that the geodesics are exactly the conics whose one focus is the point $(0,0)$ (which are the Newtonian orbits of a mass point under a fixed gravity source at the origin - the motivation of this question is to provide a geometric Newtonian theory of gravity)? For $\mathbb{R}^n$?

(Such a metric can come from an approximation of general relativity - c.f. [Newton-Cartan theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory). However, what I'm asking for is much simpler, and doesn't concern Einstein's theory).

Comment: I do not think the question makes sense: conics are defined in flat 2D space where geodesics are usual segments. Conics as approximated orbits of planets correspond to the **spatial projection** of geodesics of 4D spacetme. These projections are no longer 3D geodesics.

Comment: Geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are always straight lines independent of the chosen metric. Changing the metric, you could only transform into a system of an accelerated observer, who would observe them in different shape. But they were straight lines nevertheless.

Comment: I stated in my question that it doesn't concern Einstein's theory... perhaps it's not a suitable question for this site. Please excuse me.